# В чём разница между catch(имя_типа) и catch(имя_типа <имя_переменной>)?

Tags: c++, исключения, lambda, try-catch, лямбда-выражение

Всем здравствуйте, решил тут поиграться с блоком try, throw, catch. Написал простенькую программку для решения простых примеров с использованием лямбда-выражения, описал там блок try-catch.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double a, b;
    char c;
    std::cin >> a >> c >> b;
    auto f = [c](double a, double b)
    {
        if (c == '+') std::cout << a + b;
        if (c == '-') std::cout << a - b;
        if (c == '*') std::cout << a * b;
        if (c == '/')
        {
            try 
            {
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    throw 1;
                }
                std::cout << a / b; 
            }
            catch (int) { std::cout << "Нельзя делить на ноль!"; }
        }
    };
    f(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Тут я при делении проверяю делитель на равенство с нулём и если условие срабатывает то генерирую исключение с числом 1 (тип int). Потом как параметр для catch передаю тип int и всё работает прекрасно, но вопрос состоит в том, что можно было использовать и имя переменной данного типа, например, thr при этом она нигде ранее не была объявлена, а также любую переменную, которая вошла как параметр анонимной функции (если тип данных int, как в параметре catch).
От сюда вопрос: в чём разница между простым указанием типа и указанием типа с именем переменной? Что лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно такая же, как если функция описана как

```
void f(int) { cout << "Какое-то значение"; }
```

и как

```
void f(int i) { cout << "значение" << i; }
```

Вы просто выбрасываете информацию из сгенерированного исключения, только и всего...

Если бы вы написали

```
... catch(int i) { ... }
```

то в обработчике `i` приняла бы (в вашем случае `throw 1`) значение 1.

Comment: То есть можно указывать даже переменную-параметр функции (главное чтобы типы соответствовали)

Comment: Какой функции? Я что-то не пойму, о чем вы. Область видимости переменной в `catch` - блок обработки. В нее передается значение из `throw`. При чем тут функция?

Comment: Значит благодаря переменной мы можем конкретизировать результат обработки, ведь если с блоком try идёт 2 генерации исключения с разными числовыми значениями, то по хорошему нужно 2 catch'а ставить с обработкой каждого?

Comment: Если будут 2 `catch` с одинаковым типом (более того, например, если первый с типом класса-предка, а второй класса-потомка) - то отработает только первый соответствующий типу исключения `catch`. Получить значение вы можете только через параметр в `catch`.

Comment: Хмм, то есть в самом теле блока `catch` можно поставить условный оператор и проверять уже непосредствено там?

Comment: Да что нужно - то и ставьте. Ну набросайте тестовую программку в 5 строк и разберитесь, как оно работает...

Comment: Уже) спасибо за разъяснение